# SQL remove duplicate when order of attributes does not matter

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select S.name, T.name, S.salary, T.salary
from instructor as S, instructor as T
where S.id != T.id
and S.salary between T.salary - 100 and T.salary + 100
order by S.salary desc;
```

Output:

[image]

Is there any way to avoid duplication when the order of names does not matter so that the output is only (Shuming, Lent) or (Lent, Shuming)?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `S.id != T.id` you can use `S.id < T.id`, in an `ON` clause of a proper join:

```
select S.name, T.name, S.salary, T.salary
from instructor as S inner join instructor as T
on S.id < T.id
and S.salary between T.salary - 100 and T.salary + 100
order by S.salary desc;
```